# jQuery masked input with datepicker fires onChange event even when not changed

Tags: jquery, datepicker, mask

I have an input ( id="myDate" ), a datepicher and mask attached to it

When user presses the Tab key to circulate through all the controls, and reaches to the input "myDate",

```
__/__/____
```

is shown because of :

```
$("#myDate").mask("99/99/9999");
```

the problem is when user presses Tab to leave the control without writing anything, the onChange event is fired, which is expected only when user modifies the control value !

how to detect real change, and ignore the

```
__/__/____
```

added and removed by the jQuery mask ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update to the latest jQuery (1.9.0) and latest maskedInput (1.3.1).
This was a bug that got resolved - Look at the [change log](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JVjFn/9/) with 1.2.1 that doesn't work.
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JVjFn/6/) with 1.3.1 that does.

The code (because SO says I must):
HTML:

```
First field: <input type="text" id="bla1" name="bla"><br>
Date field: <input type="text" id="datef" name="datef"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
```

JS:

```
$("#datef").mask("99/99/9999");
$("#datef").datepicker();
$("#datef").on('change', function(){ alert('ha');});
```

Don't forget to add jQuery/jQuery-UI/and the masked plugin.
Hope this helps.